# What do I do when my boss calls me "overreacting" when I tried to be proactive about the things I need to do my job?

Tags: management

At the start of this year, I started working for a very small start-up with 7 people. It's also a distributed team. Only me and another colleague work from the new headquarters, but with the option to work from home. The CEO and CFO live in other cities as well and have no plans of moving closer to headquarters, though they alternately spend time in the office.

Our CFO insists on purchasing every work-related item. Which is kind of a logistical nightmare, because getting us the stuff we need for work is oftentimes low on the list of priorities of the CFO. When I started two weeks ago they didn't have a laptop for me because the CFO hadn't ordered it. We ended up ordering it together, but it took 10 days to arrive at the office because it turns out the CFO gave the wrong address. Another example is that it took him 10 days after I'd sent him a list of office supplies to actually order them online (we just received them today).

Then last week, I asked him to give me access to our Office 365 license. He told me to ask someone else, and of course these other colleagues don't know what to do about it. So we talked to the CFO again and he said he'd take care of it. A week passes and no updates from him, so I chase him up again about this. He said "I'll be at the office tomorrow, let's talk then. I need to go over the contract first". I responded "okay, if there's anything I can help you to get this done quickly, it would be really helpful if you could let me know. I would really like to get started on working and accessing this software is essential for that."

And that's when my boss told me "please stop overreacting about these things. I'm working on it but I have other urgent matters to take care of". At this point I am livid. I said to him "Excuse me, what do you mean I'm overreacting? I'm offering to help you get this done." And he just replied "Let's talk on the phone later." And I simply said "I'm offended by your statement, I'm afraid I can't speak on the phone right now. Perhaps we can talk tomorrow." And then I continued to work from home. He eventually did try calling me a few hours later, but I was away from my desk so I missed it. He then sent me the access details to Office 365 later that day. We haven't spoken yet.

How should I make it clear to the CFO in the most professional way possible that it was not okay brush away my efforts as "overreacting" and that it will be much better in the future if he could delegate some purchasing tasks to us (especially if the purchases *are* for us)? How can I also manage my expectations when it comes to distributed teams?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I did NOT get livid at the CFO. I was just really angry and frustrated at that point, but I didn't lash out at him. We were speaking via our messenger app.

Comment: Your question is quite long  and contains some unnecessary details. I think it would benefit from being shortened.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere of course I didn't lash out at him. This was done through a messenger app and I was as polite as I could. Also, he was the one who  wanted to postpone the conversation.

Comment: Can you make the objective of your question more clear? "How should I proceed in this case?" is fairly open ended. Is the goal to learn how to better manage your expectations, better communicate your challenges to your boss, both, something else?

Comment: 'And he just replied "Let's talk on the phone later." And I simply said "I'm offended by your statement, I'm afraid I can't speak on the phone right now.' --
Is it fair to say, that sometimes you are reacting passionately?

Comment: @Helena sometimes, I admit. However, this is how he responds to everyone: he'll make his point and people ask for clarification, but then will only say "let's talk about this later". And so we're often left wondering what to make of his words. My feeling was this: I haven't gotten any work done in the last weeks because I didn't have the tools I needed. And when I tried to be proactive I get told I'm overreacting, and when I asked for clarification he cuts the conversation off? At that point I felt like I couldn't speak to him professionally so I had to be honest.

Comment: "_if there's anything I can help you to get this done quickly, it would be really helpful if you could let me know_" You should of shortend this to **Let me know if there's anything I can do to help**. That way it sounds like you want to be helpful rather than negging to get it done quicker

Comment: @dustytrash I find that no one really means it when they say it. So I wanted to emphasize that I would like to help to get the process moving along.

Comment: @iamnarra You have to balance being "real" and being polite. For example, you're most likely lying when you ask how someones day was. It's just part of being in the workforce.

Answer (score 5):

In a comment you said,

> And so we're often left wondering what to make of his words

But his words seem pretty clear to me: He knows you have a need, but he is busy with more important things.

Sometimes, in work, you get hung up waiting for other people. When you're not in a position to dictate someone else's priorities, or change procedures, that's just part of having a job. It can be frustrating, and if it is frustrating enough, you may decide to look for employment elsewhere.

But it can also help to gut check your expectations. It sounds like you've been at this employer for a few weeks. That's not a very long track record, and if they're in the middle of something really important, they may be totally happy paying you to sit and wait and get no work done until they can help get you set up. Setting up a license or buying computer equipment may sound trivial to you, but in a bustling startup, it might not be unusual to have to wait for a few weeks or months to have every detail squared away. In a small company, leaders often wear lots of hats, and it can be incredibly challenging to juggle different responsibilities. Waiting a few weeks to have some office supplies might seem crippling to you, but it may legitimately not be the most important thing on a CFO's plate at the moment.

If your goal is to keep your job and mend relationships, you should start paying attention to the literal meaning of what your CFO and your boss are telling you. They are telling you that they've heard your request and they will get to it when they have time. That probably means that you don't have to follow up or escalate, and if you do, they may legitimately see it as you "over reacting" in the sense that they are already aware of your need. And, certainly, a boss asking an employee for a phone call and basically being told "sorry boss, you've made me so upset I can't talk right now, maybe tomorrow" is a pretty strong reaction for you to have.

If your goal is to get out of this situation because you don't like the culture, you should still think carefully about how all of this is unfolding. Is there anything about the undesirable culture that *you are contributing to?* Are there things you could change about your approach to help avoid this sort of problem? Thinking about these things can help you start off your next job in better standing, instead of potentially repeating the same situation again.

Also, if you decide to look elsewhere, reflecting on the situation will help you clarify what you need in order to be happy and successful. If you feel you absolutely must have all office supplies, licenses, and computer equipment ready to go on day one, you should find out how to determine if that will happen at a potential employer. Whatever it is you decide you need, either ask about it in interviews, or take other steps to determine if a new employer's culture will be a good fit for you. Remember, interviews are a two way street: the company will evaluate you, but you must also evaluate the company and decide if you will be happy there. It would be a shame to leave this job, only to hop into another one where you are unhappy for the same reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response and I get what you're saying. Thing is, I already have projects lined up, so it's not like my to-do list is short. I've just had to do everything on my own laptop which has a ton of issues (client privacy mostly). That's why those of us in the office want to take on more responsibilities, like office management etc. We've expressed many times that we'd like to take over these tasks, but he refuses to delegate. I would have gladly gone over the contract and told him what needed to be done, at what price. That's what I am frustrated about.

Comment: There are lots of things that my boss is responsible for, yet I am capable of doing myself. Sometimes, I have to wait around for him to do those things. That doesn't change the fact that it's his job to do those things, even if I offer to help with them. Offering to help is great, but you have to realize, it's still ultimately someone else's responsibility, and your CFO is under no obligation to delegate.

Comment: that's true. I'm still hoping the situation will change. It doesn't help that he's in another city, so I think that letting us manage our office would be easier for him in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. You're (rightly) passionate about getting your work done.

Your CFO is obviously inexperienced. He (rightly) doesn't want your little startup to blow through all its precious investor money spending it on stuff you don't need. So he (wrongly) controls spending by doing it all himself.

By impeding your work he is, unintentionally, spending a dollar to save a penny. The most valuable things for startups are time-to-market and salary costs. By worrying over such things as the cost of a software license or laptop computer he's making you waste your time, again unintentionally. Your time is the company's time. You're in a race for survival as a startup.

You are right to question this policy controlling spending. And you're understandably frustrated.   About expressing your frustration, I would speak to him privately and apologize for your evident irritation. It should be no big deal.

If it were me, with my startup experience, I would write a note to all the executives  / founders of the company saying something like  this

> As our staff grows we need to do purchasing more quickly, especially for new hires. May I suggest this policy?  Set a budget to buy equipment for each new hire, then let the person herself, or her manager, buy the necessary equipment and licenses using a credit card, then submit an expense claim for reimbursement.
>
> My experience coming on board at xxxx company shows that a budget of $x,xxx is appropriate, including blah, blah, and blah.
>
> I am willing, personally, to do my part with this to help xxxx company grow and get our product to market as quickly as possible.

(Notice how I mentioned the company name twice? It's a route to founders' hearts. Seriously.)

This kind of suggestion may shake them up a bit. It may take them days or even weeks to wrap their heads around it. They may come up with something else instead. But they will think about it.

If your executives continue to micromanage this kind of  stuff when you get up to 20 people or so, I hate to say it: the company may have trouble staying  in business because the executives are thinking about the wrong things.